# Vue Mounting Component removing div

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to mount a component on a function, it works fine. However I've got it setup so that it destroys the div after X amount of seconds. Then when I try and add the compoent again its removed the base div. I'm not sure how to fix this though...

Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-alert show dismissible variant="danger">
        <i class="mdi mdi-block-helper mr-2"></i>{{ text }}
    </b-alert>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
    name: "alertDanager",
    props: {
    text: null
    },
    created() {
        setTimeout(() => this.destoryEl(), 5000);
    },
    methods: {
        destoryEl() {
            this.$destroy();
            this.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$el);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Spawning the component in

```
const DangerAlertExtended = Vue.extend(dangerAlert);
const error = new DangerAlertExtended({ propsData: { text: "Error message" } });
error.$mount("#error");
```

I'm not sure how to make it stop overwriting the #error div...

Answer (score 0):

Why not let `v-if` exclude it from the DOM instead of removing the element?  Alternatively, it could be hidden but remain in the DOM with `v-show` (that's probably what I would do, unless there's a specific reason you need for it to not be in the DOM).  I think it's generally better to let Vue manage the DOM rather than manipulate yourself.

```
<template>
  <div v-if="showAlert">
    <b-alert show dismissible variant="danger">
        <i class="mdi mdi-block-helper mr-2"></i>{{ text }}
    </b-alert>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
    name: "alertDanager",
    props: {
        text: null,
        showAlert: true
    },
    created() {
        setTimeout(() => this.hideAlert(), 5000);
    },
    methods: {
        hideAlert() {
            this.showAlert = false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've been looking at a few on github and they all seem to be doing that. I guess I'm just use to JQuery. I'll try and change my ways a little.

Comment: I think when you start using libraries that use a virtual DOM, there's a lot of lifecycle management stuff it does that just make it inadvisable to try to manipulate yourself generally.